# UK emergency travel document to go to US then Mexico?

Tags: usa, uk

I live in Spain and I recently lost my passport and I'm trying to obtain an emergency travel document from the British Embassy. This allows me to travel within 5 different countries, however 'visas might be necessary'.

On 15th November I will travel from Barcelona to Los Angeles and stay there 36 hours. I will then fly to Mexico where I will be for almost 3 weeks. On 4th December I will go back to Los Angeles at 11 am and fly back to BCN at 20:45.

It seems that I need a US visa along with my emergency travel document. However the visa process seems to take around 3 weeks and mentions appointments (I do not have 3 weeks).

I called the US visa advice line and they pointed me to [the US Customs website](https://www.cbp.gov/). The number on their site went to a phone matrix which talks about the details for Mexican and Canadian travellers. I could not get to an agent...

Does anyone know if anything can be done or exists in this shitty situation, or should I cancel my trip and holiday on the Spanish cost without needing a passport?

The emergency passport seems useful but its use and immediacy seems to stop with things like the US visa process.

Thanks for advice or links and I can provide more info/details if it's needed.

Tom

Answer (score 4):

Your information is correct.  The UK emergency passport is not an e-passport, so it does not allow you to use the US [visa waiver program](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html).

You can consider a couple of options.

1) Travel to the UK and [make an expedited passport application](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently).

2) Try to get an expedited visa appointment.  One way to do that is [to have been denied ESTA authorization](https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-es/niv/information/faqs#qualify_vwp).  You may be able to get an ESTA denial by applying for it with your non-qualifying emergency passport, but I am not sure whether the application actually asks about that.

Another option, of course, would be to travel to Mexico without passing through the US.